# Does having the same variable for pattern matching in Erlang means the value are same?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I have some code like this:

```
hdistance([H|T], [H1|T1], Distance) when H /= H1 ->
        hdistance(T, T1, Distance + 1);

hdistance([H|T], [H1|T1], Distance) when H == H1 ->
        hdistance(T, T1, Distance).
```

Can I get rid of the `when` clause by doing it like this:

```
hdistance([H|T], [H|T1], Distance) ->
        hdistance(T, T1, Distance + 1);

hdistance([H|T], [H1|T1], Distance) ->
        hdistance(T, T1, Distance).
```

If yes why and if no why not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

> If yes why

Based on my experience with maps, I remember formulating a rule that the order of matching is not guaranteed, but once one of the lists matches and H is bound to a value, then the other list will only match if the head of the list is equal to H.

You may have experienced something similar in the shell when you wrote:

```
2> X = 10.
```

then sometime later, you wrote:

```
5> X = 20.
```

and you got an error that said, "no match of right hand side".  For the first "match", X was bound to 10; then for the second match because 20 does not match 10, you get an error.  It works the same way for your lists: H gets bound to a value for the first match, then for the second match the head of the list has to equal H.

You can actually write the second clause like this:

```
hdistance([_|T], [_|T1], Distance) ->
        hdistance(T, T1, Distance).
```

because execution will only get to the second clause if the heads of the lists are not equal.